# how should i call prepareProductdetailpage method from catalogController to my pluging's controller

Tags: nopcommerce

I want to increment counter of product when product visited by client. I was done this without plugin

First i was made insert method in `productservice` :

```
public virtual void InsertMostViewProduct(int productid)
        {
            var query = from u in _mostviewRepository.Table
                        where u.ProductId == productid
                        select u;

       if (query.Count()==0)
        {
            //insert
            var Insertproduct = new MostViewProduct();
            Insertproduct.ProductId = productid;
            Insertproduct.ProductCount = 1;
            _mostviewRepository.Insert(Insertproduct);

            //event notification
            _eventPublisher.EntityInserted(Insertproduct);
        }
        else
        {
          //Update
            var product = query.FirstOrDefault();
            product.ProductCount = product.ProductCount + 1;
            _mostviewRepository.Update(product);
          //  _eventPublisher.EntityUpdated(Updateproduct);
        }

    }
```

And called this method in `PrepareProductDetailsPageModel` :

```
 #region MostViewProduct

        _productService.InsertMostViewProduct(product.Id);

 #endregion
```

How should i call `prepareProductdetailpage` method from `catalogController` to my pluging's controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code the `PrepareProductDetailsPageModel` is not a good place for your code as it is also called for the associated products list. Furthermore, I suggest you not to modify nopCommerce code when possible.

My suggestion is do it in your plugin. Override the implementation of the `IRecentlyViewedProductsService` within your plugin, this service is called every time an user visits a product page.

1. Add a class to your plugin extending `RecentlyViewedProductsService`. Override the `AddProductToRecentlyViewedList` method adding your own code. Be sure to call the implementation from the base class to keep old functionality.
2. Register the new service in the Dependency registrar of your plugin ([more](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/17601/override-method-in-pictureservice-from-a-plugin.aspx)).

If you need more flexibility consider creating a custom event and handler ([more](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/12719/how-to-subscribe-to-an-event-in-a-plugin.aspx)), in this case you will need to modify the original code to properly wire it up.